# If $a=\sin37^\circ$, what is $\sin2017^\circ$?

Tags: trigonometry

If $a=\sin37^\circ$, what is $\sin2017^\circ$?

We have $$\sin2017^\circ=(360^\circ\cdot5+217^\circ)=\sin217^\circ$$

Then I noted $$\sin(217^\circ-37^\circ)=\sin180^\circ\iff \sin217^\circ\cos37^\circ-\cos217^\circ\sin37^\circ=0\\x\sqrt{1-a^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}a=0,$$ where $x=\sin217^\circ$. I don't see if we can find $x$ from here, or is there an easier approach?

Comment: $\sin2017^\circ=(360^\circ\cdot5+217^\circ)=sin217^\circ=sin(180+37)^\circ=-sin37^\circ=-a$

Comment: You noted $2017=180+37.$ Now, $\sin(180^\circ+t^\circ)=-\sin(t^\circ)$ (no need of trigonometric formula for this: just look at the unit circle; when you rotate a half turn, both $\sin$ and $\cos$ are changed to their opposites).

Comment: @AnneBauval, obviously not.

Comment: This was not a true question (it was automatically generated when I voted to close for duplication). To me and at least one other answerer, it obviously does, since it shows that $\sin(217^\circ)$ and $\sin(37^\circ)$ are mutual opposites.